# Why does property key not get substituted with value while doing bean initialization from the properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have a spring boot application (Let's call it `project A`) which I am configuring by Java configuration. This spring boot has a dependency with a small sub project (Let's call it `project B`) via pom dependencies, which is in a jar (which is also implemented using spring framework).

`project A` has Java configuration `@Configuration`, while `project B` also has `ApplicationContext-b.xml`.
I am forcing it to get loaded by using

```
@XmlBConfigruation(locations=classpath:ApplicationContext-b-xml.)
```

This `project B` application context uses some properties like below.

In the main `project A`, I have an `xxx-soa.properties` file which has this key and the value `${com.caiso.soa.saas.samlEncryptionKeyStoreConfiguration.store`.
This key never gets injected with the actual value in the file.

```
<bean id="samlEncryptionKeyStoreConfiguration"
    class="com.xxxx.soa.saas.support.KeystoreConfiguration">
    <property name="store"   value="${com.xxxx.soa.saas.samlEncryptionKeyStoreConfiguration.store}" />
    <property name="type">
        <value>jks</value>
    </property>
    <property name="alias">
        <value>oati_b2b_test</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>changeit</value>
    </property>
    <property name="digestAlgorithm">
        <value>http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="signingAlgorithm">
        <value>http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

What I have already tried

TRIAL ONE
In `project A`

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:omsoati-app.properties", "classpath:omsint-framework-ws.properties", "**classpath:caiso-soa.properties**" })
@Import({ XxxxSoaSaasXmlConfiguration.class, OmsoatiAdapterConfiguration.class })
```

Jar which is dependency for `project A` 
In `project B`, property files are in the `web-inf\classess` folder in the war/jar

TRIAL TWO
In `project B`'s `applicationContext-b.xml` I also tried declaring like below as well.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:caiso-soa.properties"  ignore-resource-not-found="false" />
```

But nothing works.

I have attached the log file [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/files/2139177/log.txt). It clearly shows that it is able to load the property files at line number 756

> 2018-06-26 15:22:58,773 DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'com.caiso.soa.saas.samlEncryptionKeyStoreConfiguration.store' in [class path resource [caiso-soa.properties]] with type [String]

Comment: What is that `@XmlBConfigruation` annotation? That appears to by pass the regular spring `@ImportResource` looks like you are doing things in a way you shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: Let me edit that actually it is typo actually it suppose to be @Configruation

Comment: The problem is more like your main project loading the application context of the one of the dependent project , somehting similar , http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring  kind of parent context and the child context.